# Help with calculation of crossing more than expected from observed vs simulated data

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, biostatistics, contingency-tables

I want to know if moose are crossing water more than expected.  I followed the methods written in Beyer et al 2013 which I am now completely confused as to how to actually do the analysis.  I am hoping someone would be willing to help explain the steps - because I think i am simply overly complicating it or I am missing one critical step.

I have my observed path for each moose (N = 29).  Paths can be 6 to 58 "steps" long (steps are the connecting lines between 2 consecutive points).  For each path I have a count of crossings.

I have generated 200 correlated random walks (simulated data) for EACH moose path.  This too I have the count of crossings.

Beyer et al paper says:

> The probability density (Pr) of the observed road-crossing rate (cr)
>   for a given moose and season was calculated based on the cumulative
>   distribution function of the expected distribution of road crossings
>   derived from the CRW simulations (D). Specifically, Pr is calculated
>   as the position of cr in the ordered list of all D, divided by the
>   total number of observations in D and cr (1001 in this analysis). If
>   ties occur (i.e. if cr is identical to one or more values in D), the
>   median ranked position among all ties was used. The value of Pr, which
>   is always in the range [0,1], is a measure of the response of moose to
>   roads (hereafter referred to as the ‘road response index’).

Im at a loss of how to start to implement this analysis.  Im unsure what D is, and how the tie is calculated.  About all I think I can get is that Pr is the position of the cr value (not the actual value of cr, but the ordered number) in the list of D.  But what is all D?  Is that D for 1 animal, or D for all animals?

How to calculate the expected cumulative distribution? Do I take simulated path #1 and it crossed 4 times which I then divide by 200 (total Simulated paths for that 1 animal), or do I divide it by the total possible times it could have crossed?  Meaning path 1 was made up of 10 steps.  Then what is divided by all D?

As you can likely tell, Im getting myself more and more confused and I would really appreciate some assistance in clarification of this analysis.  OR If someone has an alternative option??  Id be grateful for suggested examples from other data where you compare observed vs. random simulation data.  Even if its a homework assgnment where the steps are walked through.

Comment: It sounds like if you had observed 7 crossings, and had 5 simulated crossings of  3,5,7,9,11, then pr=3/5.

Comment: Could you give a complete reference please? Is it [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1365-2664.12042/abstract)?

Comment: The quoted text is not describing a chi-square.

Comment: @Glen_b you are correct that it is an article the article is Functional responses, seasonal variation and threshiolds in behavioural responses of moose to road density, Beyer et al 2013. Journal of Applied Ecology.

Comment: The crux of the matter, Kerry, concerns the model of moose behavior adopted in the paper and how that was exploited to generate the "CRW" simulations. Only people with access to this (restricted) paper will be able to address this unless you include a sufficiently clear description in the question.